# jQuery UI autocomplete POSTs input to controller, but does not autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is my first time trying to use jQuery autocomplete and I feel like I am most of the way there, but the autocomplete is not working.

I am using a textarea with a `data-autocomplete-url` to pass the input to my controller action:

```
<textarea id="assign-to" rows="1" data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("AutoCompleteUsername")"></textarea>
```

This is what should allow the autocomplete to work?:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*[data-autocomplete-url]")
        .each(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url")
        });
    });
});
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult AutoCompleteUsername(string term)
    {
        using (var entity = new TestEntities())
        {
            var users = entity.uspSearchUserByName(term).ToList();

            return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The input is getting POSTed to the controller action and is being filtered through my stored procedure. The disconnect for me is how the data for the autocomplete is actually being returned to the textarea. Right now it seems like I am just returning the data to no where.

Within users, there is both a Username and Id being returned. I am unsure how to set the value and label for the autocomplete.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), you need to return the JSON data as an array of objects with label and value properties.

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

In the autocomplete dropdown, the labels will be shown and after you select an option, the corresponding value will be set into your textarea.